# Old JS Fullscreen code no longer working. "requestFullscreen is not a function" error

Tags: html5-fullscreen

**EDIT: An answer is accepted below, but for anyone who ends up in my position, the main issue was that firefox temporarily enabled full-screen-api.unprefix by default, and then changed that in an update so that a prefix was once again necessary.  Also, if you search about:config for "fullscreen" it won't show "full-screen-api."**

Some code I have been using for a long time to fullscreen webpages using js no longer works.

I've checked the mdn (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen) and nothing appears to have changed, but for some reason I can no longer full screen a website in any of my browsers (I've tested Chrome, Firefox, and Firefox Developer Edition).

Further, the error I'm given is not one of permissions, but that `requestFullscreen` does not appear to exist as a function.

```
TypeError: document.body.requestFullscreen is not a function
```

Is something big going on that I just don't know about?  Is this perhaps related to my OS?  It's very odd that old code (`document.body.requestFullscreen()`) which worked in all my browsers no more than 6 months ago now works in none.

Also, I've tested it where I use it most and fullscreen does still work for things like youtube or the built in bits `<video>` tags.

```css
#test {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="document.body.requestFullscreen()">Fullscreen document.body</button>

<button onclick="document.documentElement.requestFullscreen()">Fullscreen document.documentElement</button>

<button onclick="document.documentElement.requestFullscreen()">Fullscreen Test Div</button>

<div id="test">Test Div</div>
```

Comment: It's `requestFullscreen` with a lowercase `s`. Voting to close as off-topic because this was a typo.

Comment: Fixed that and it still doesn't work

Comment: The typo was in my snippet, but my old code had no typo, and was working as said.  It has since stopped.

Comment: It's experimental. Check the browser compatibility on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen

Comment: @Quentin I linked that very same mdn above, it's the first place I looked. Experimental or not, it used to work, and now it does not.  A reason why is what I'm looking for.

Comment: On Chrome you have to do `webkitRequestFullScreen` and on Firefox `mozRequestFullScreen`. If you haven't used only IE earlier, it's possible that the non-prefixed method was briefly implemented on some versions.

Comment: @JJJ This solved my problem and thank you.  I think this must have been what happened.  If you'd like to make this an answer, I'll accept it.  Btw, it's lowercase `s` in `mozRequestFullscreen`

Comment: @JJJ — That's *old* firefox. In new Firefox you have to use `requestFullscreen` and turn on the config to allow it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: Three years later and the feature is no longer experimental. Prefixes are only needed for Internet Explorer and Safari in 2020.

---

As per the browser support section of [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen):

This is an experimental feature.

Chrome only supports it with the `webkit` prefix. Firefox only supports it if you turn on the `full-screen-api.unprefix.enabled` preference in the browser. Internet Explorer only supports it with the `ms` prefix.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of implementing the vendor-prefixed fullscreen api requests:

```
function toggleFullScreen() {
    // Get your full screen element
    const video= document.querySelector('.player');
    const rfs = video.requestFullscreen || video.webkitRequestFullScreen || video.mozRequestFullScreen || video.msRequestFullscreen;
    rfs.call(video);
}
```

addEventListener for'click' on your button:

```
const fullscreenBtn = player.querySelector('.fullscreen-btn');
fullscreenBtn.addEventListener('click', toggleFullScreen);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be helpful to someone.

So I was having an issue with the fullscreen function on a website I am working on (svejen.ikbugu.com) .

For me, the IE and Chrome fullscreen was working, but Firefox not. No errors were thrown out and the function was executing well under 1 sec ( somewhere I read that if over 1 sec., firefox prevents the fullscreen request from executing). I also had the request with and without the vendor specific prefixes, so that was not it.

What worked for me  was to paste the javascript directly into the html as opposed to have it stored in a separate file. Now it works perfectly.

I thought this might help someone else who is having the same issue... Greetings.